# vscodeのextensionがnodeを見つけられない

Tags: node.js, vscode, zenn

vscodeでzenn-editorを使っているのですが、新しい記事の作成ができなくなりました。
「zenn-editor.create-new-article」ボタンを押すと、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
Error running command zenn-editor.create-new-article: Article creation failed (exit code: 127): env: node: No such file or directory . This is likely caused by the extension that contributes zenn-editor.create-new-article.
```

macos ventura 13.6（22G120）
vscode Version: 1.84.2 (Universal)
zen-editor 0.9.1
node v18.18.2

以下の状況

- vscodeのターミナルからnodeは見える
  -`node -v` できる
- vscodeのターミナルからzen-cliは使える
  -`npx zenn new:article` できる
  -`npx zenn preview` できる

以下を試しました。

- zen-editor extensionの再インストール効果なし
- vs-code再起動効果なし
- PC再起動効果なし
- node-modulesフォルダ削除、yarn installの再実行、効果なし
- zenncliの更新 `npm install zenn-cli@latest`効果なし
- zen-editorのバージョンを古くしてみるcurrent 0.9.1 older 0.9.0 効果なし

vscodeのextensionのzenn-editorからnodeが見えていないっぽいのかなと思うのですが、どうすれば改善するのかわからず。わかることあったら教えていただきたいです。